# How can I determine which libraries are loaded/needed?

Tags: java, jar, libraries, loaded

I developing webservice application with IntelliJ IDEA, using Apache CXF, Spring, Hibernate and some more. All these framework are ship with a lot of libraries, but I do not use all of them.

At the moment I waste a lot of time to determine which jar files I have to deploy into the production enviroment to ensure a properly working system.

Is there an easy and fast way to determine which libraries, more precise which jar files are loaded/needed by my application.

Comment: You can try this : http://code.google.com/p/loosejar/

Comment: @Ramadas: convert your comment to an answer to gain reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).  It's the most popular dependency management tool in the Java world.

Answer (score 1):

Try Loosejar: **http://code.google.com/p/loosejar/**

For demo, I ran the Loosejar agent against a small applications in my eclipse workshop. The application uses 4 jars (jsoup-1.6.1.jar, httpclient-4.2.3.jar, httpcore-4.2.2.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar). I added an unused jar file to the build path- “soap-2.3.1.jar” and started the application. Then opened jconsole and viewed the summary of LooseJarMBean(screen shot below). The results show the no of used classes from each jar. Unused jars will be shown with 0% utilization

[image]

Another way is to do it manually. In one of our projects we added jars manually to project until all compilation issues are resolved. This approach has a limitation where if a jar refers another jar then we will get to know about it only during run time.

Comment: loosejar works great, I also will give Maven a chance, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) it might be able to list all your library dependecies.